# How to fix missing dependency operator error in FreeBSD?

Tags: makefile, freebsd

Below make code normally works fine, but Github freebsd code test doesn't like it. Here's the error I get:

> cd src && make first
>
> make[1]: "/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/src/Makefile" line 1394: Missing dependency operator
>
> make[1]: "/tmp/cirrus-ci-build/src/Makefile" line 1396: Need an operator
>
> make[1]: Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
>
> make[1]: stopped in /tmp/cirrus-ci-build/src
>
> *** [first] Error code 1

Errors correspond to the `ifeq` and `endif` lines. I've also tried ditching the `+=` operator and declaring an `else` to write separately, still the same error. What could be the issue here?

Code below, thanks in advance.

```
HAIKUGUI_LIBS1  = -lbe -lroot -ltracker -ltranslation
ifeq ($(strip $(word 1, $(subst -, , $(subst ., , $(shell $(CC) -dumpversion))))), 8)
HAIKUGUI_LIBS1  += -lsupc++ -lstdc++
endif
```

Comment: `ifeq` and `endif` are Gnu Make extensions.  Q: Are you using Gnu Make? Look [here](http://alfix.gitlab.io/bsd/gnu/coding/2017/01/28/gnu-make-vs-bsd-make.html) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127954/how-to-install-gnu-make-on-freebsd-10)

Comment: `pkg install gmake` & `cd src && gmake first`.

Comment: @FoggyDay, Yes, it's GNUmake. I've tried modifying the syntax according to the differences, but it didn't work. I got rid of the check altogether. Do you have any idea how to write it bmake friendly?

Comment: When you say "Yes it's GNU make" I assume you mean, yes, the problem is that you're _not_ using GNU make.  Those errors are definitely not generated by GNU make.  There is no way to write a makefile that is compatible between BSD make and GNU make, unless it uses only the most basic POSIX make syntax (and there's no equivalent of something like `ifeq` in POSIX make).  For any but the most basic makefile you'll have to just pick one advanced make version and use that everywhere.